# Summing 2D list columns where some elements are strings

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists of the form:

```
my_list=[[1,2,'A'],[4,5,'B'],[7,8,'C']]
```

and I want to sum the first element of each list (1+4+7) to get a total. I tried the following which didn't work because some elements of the list are strings:

```
new_list = list(zip(*my_list))
print (sum(new_list[0]))
```

What is the best way to do this without using loops?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sum(a[0] for a in my_list)
```

is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming every sub-list has three elements, you can do this:

```
sum( a for (a,_,_) in my_list )
```

Otherwise, do this:

```
sum( a[0] for a in my_list )
```

Technically, these use loops in the guise of generators, but anything you pass to sum will end up looping, one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> my_list
[[1, 2, 'A'], [4, 5, 'B'], [7, 8, 'C']]
>>> sum([a[0] for a in my_list])
12
>>>
```

Will create a list consisting of the first element of each element in `my_list`, and sum them.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: import operator

In [2]: my_list=[[1,2,'A'],[4,5,'B'],[7,8,'C']]

In [3]: sum(map(operator.itemgetter(0),my_list))
Out[3]: 12
```

Or using a generator expression:

```
In [4]: sum(row[0] for row in my_list)
Out[4]: 12
```

The generator expression is quicker, and easier to read:

```
In [5]: %timeit sum(map(operator.itemgetter(0),my_list))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.52 us per loop

In [6]: %timeit sum(row[0] for row in my_list)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.02 us per loop
```